# Can you get all PvP commons from PvE packs?

Tags: hex-tcg

While playing the Hex campaign, I noticed that the PvE packs contained two commons from PvP sets and one PvE exclusive card (also two slots for equipment or stardust). Are those commons from a set pool, or can they be anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commons are from a limited pool, so you won't be able to get all PVP commons that way.  From [the website](https://www.hextcg.com/pve-campaign-overview/)

> packs will always contain five total reward items, which will consist
>   of some combination of equipment, PvE cards, Stardust, and **a subset of PvP commons**

Of course you can always pick up commons from the Auction House using the gold you earn in the campaign.